# Volume of a polar solid of known cross section

Tags: calculus, volume, cross-sections

I am trying to generate a solid of known cross sections to be semi-circles for the cardioid $r = 1 + \sin\theta$.  I figured that I would need to calculate the volume of individual wedges and sum all of them.  My thought was that I needed to use shell method and multiply by $\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}$ in order to get the minuscule volume associated with $d\theta$.  I was wondering if anyone could help me correctly employ the shell method in order to obtain the correct equation that would generate the correct volume.  I've searched online and the solution is nowhere to be found so this could be a great opportunity to discover something new.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what solid you're defining. So you're starting with this : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cardioid, what do you do then to get the solid? Revolve around some axis?

Comment: Yes, so I began with a cardioid. The solid is then generated by putting semi-circles on each _r_ so that one end of the semi-circle is on the origin and the other is placed on the corresponding point $(r, \theta)$, no revolution.  The resulting solid will look kind of like the front half of an apple, if that helps clarify.  I apologize for the confusion, its just difficult to explain through text.

Comment: If you could explain through equations, you could also compute! What have you tried so far?

Comment: My equation so far is $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{r} x\sqrt{(\frac{r}{2})^2-(x-\frac{r}{2})^2}\cdot dx\cdot d\theta$$ \\ Where $ \int_{0}^{r} x\sqrt{(\frac{r}{2})^2-(x-\frac{r}{2})^2}\cdot dx$ is my application of shell method and the $\int_{0}^{2\pi} u \cdot d\theta$ is the sum of the wedges.  I am pretty confident in the wedge summing part, but I am not sure if my application of shell method is correct.  I've been debating a substitution of $x$ for $r$ but I am not confident that that makes logical sense.  I can't figure out how to correctly calculate the shells.

Comment: See this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration. Can you describe your function "$f$" (the one mentioned in the link, i.e. the function whose graph is revolved around the vertical axis)? I can't quite figure out which one you want to use.

Comment: For any $x$, the $f(x)$ value will be $\sqrt{\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\frac{r}{2}\right)^2}$ because $(f(x))^2 + (x-\frac{r}{2})^2 = (\frac{r}{2})^2$ where $r$ is the value that satisfies the equation $r = 1+\sin\theta$ for the $\theta$ in question so I believe that the $f$ should be $\sqrt{\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\frac{r}{2}\right)^2}$.  However, finding the correct function $f$ is pretty much where I am confusing myself the most.

Comment: The function $f$ should not depend on $r$, that's why you're confused. When you rotate around the $y$ axis, you are computing the volume under the graph of the function $g(r,\theta) = f(r)$. So if you're trying to express $f(x)$ for your geometric shape and then rotate it around the axis, it shouldn't depend on $r$ to begin with since you didn't even rotate yet! Try thinking about it some more.